# How to change font so simillar characters can be distinguished in Keepass 2?

Tags: password-management, keepass

I've had problems at work and at home where password managers display similar letters virtually identically. For example it's impossible to distinguish between an 1, l and I. Is there a recommended font to use? I've found Times New Roman in Word is generally distinguishable. How can the font be changed in Keepass 2?

Comment: Courier New has distinct patterns for each character.

Comment: This is a Keepass config question and not a infosec question. Ask their support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose one of the available fonts by following this path:

```
Tools/Options
```

Once there, choose the tab called `Interface`.

Comment: You can also increase the size there, which I find fairly necessary.